# Is there a way to hash JIRA issues into a fixed number of buckets?

Tags: jira, jql

I want to split a large number of JIRA issues into buckets automatically so that I can review a fixed fraction of them at a time via a JQL query. Unfortunately my options seem to be limited or nonexistent; one easy method would be to take the numeric portion of the key, modulo some fixed number N, but there's [no modulo operator in JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver0813/advanced-searching-operators-reference-1027135328.html) (indeed, no arithmetic operators at all, just relational operators that return boolean values). Then I could execute a series of JIRA queries like this:

```
PROJECT = FOO AND HASH(KEY,12) = 0
PROJECT = FOO AND HASH(KEY,12) = 1
PROJECT = FOO AND HASH(KEY,12) = 2
  ...
PROJECT = FOO AND HASH(KEY,12) = 11
```

But there is no such thing; I can't extract various pieces of the creation date (day of the week, hour of the day, month of the year), and I'm stumped how I might do this.

The alternative is to manually maintain some kind of field like a label, and split the issues manually, but this is very tedious.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not exactly hash data, you can partition issues based on the issue number, which might potentially meet your needs. Caveats are that the order will be nonrandom, any gaps in the issue number sequence would produce partitions of different sizes, and you would need to know which issue number ranges you are targeting.

For example, the following JQL would extract two sets of 100 issues from the project FOO:

```
issue >= FOO-1 and issue <= FOO-100
issue > FOO-100 and issue <= FOO-200
```

Comment: yeah, that's problematic because the distribution of unresolved issues is unequal, much fewer with lower key numbers, which is why I wanted to hash the key to reduce significance of the MSBs. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the third-party [ScriptRunner](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com) app installed, you can also use JQL such as the following to match an issue field against a regular expression. For example, the following query would match all issues with an issue key ending in an even digit. You could extrapolate this to match against multiple digits of the issue key to create more than 10 ranges, or even try to apply the matching against a different field.

```
issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("", "issuekey", "[02468]$")
```

Comment: thx, not sure we have that plugin -- if so, great; if not, i'm out of luck; our jira admins are hard to convince to install new ones.